# What is innerHTML property in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

innerHTML property is used to change the text inside html. This is the only thing that the innerHTML will do (or) Is there any other uses?

Comment: `innerHTML` changes the HTML contents of an element. If that's not enough of a use for you... well, what do you want? XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it's a setter and getter for the serialised DOM of all children elements from the reference.

It should not be used because you want to *change the text inside* (there's `textContent` for that).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you know it's a setter and getter for serialized DOM content? Because that sounds like an implementation specific thing (afaik all "standards" before html5 didn't bother to go into such detail) left to the browser vendor ...  Have you got any links on this perhaps? Would be interested!

Answer (score 0):

It's a read/write property.

That means that you could also get the HTML inside a hidden div, for example, and store in a variable. Then you could put the data from the variable inside another not hidden div, when you need it always using the same property. Just think to a slideshow.

Comment: ... or even from a DocumentFragment which isn't even part of the rendered DOM.